# Why does the if statement "if(1)" give error in Java but it holds true in C++?

Tags: java, c++, if-statement

It might be trivial, but I am a beginner in Java so any help will be much appreciated!
The error I get if I run the program

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        if(1)
           System.out.println("Hello World!");
    }
}
```

is

> Main.java:3: error: incompatible types: int cannot be converted to boolean
>           if(1)
>              ^

but the following code in C++ works

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main() {
    if(1)
        cout<<"Hello World!";
}
```

Does Java not consider 0 as false and any number other than 0 true, like in C++?

Comment: Different languages. Difference rules.

Comment: Java and C++ are completly different languages. Do not expect what works in one will work in the other.  They have different styles of coding and you should forget you even know C++ and just learn Java like you would if it is your first language.  That will help you to get into the Java frame of mind.

Comment: I disagree with the close reason being "_This question is opinion-based._" How is this question opinion-based? This question is about different rules, of different languages. Those rules are defined, and not a subject to an opinion.

Comment: @NathanOliver-ReinstateMonica Yes, I would agree, that closing it as a dupe, with the target, you linked to, would be much more accurate, than this question being "opinion-based".

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius Alright, now it is a duplicate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason for that is simple - in java every condition must be resolved as a boolean value (true of false) while in c / c++ false is 0 while true is anything else...

Comment: To clarify: In C++, other integer types implicitly convert to `bool`.